# Corollary of Nakayama's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

In the book "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" from S.Bosch, on page 37 there is a Corollary (n°11) of the Nakayama's Lemma:

"Let M be a finitely generated $R$-module and $Q\subset J(R)$ an ideal. Then if $N\subset M$ is an $R$-submodule satisfying $M = N+QM$, we must have $M=N$"

The proof is clear to me, generally speaking: it applies directly the Nakayama's Lemma to $M/N$ in order to say that $M/N = \{0\} \Rightarrow M=N$. It's not fully clear the first statement i.e $M/N = Q(M/N)$ (a). Indeed with the third isomorphism theorem, I would say that

$\dfrac{M}{N} = \dfrac{N+QM}{N} \sim \dfrac{QM}{QM\cap N}$

I think this is the wrong way to prove (a), mostly because I got isomorphic and not equal as required by Nakayama's Lemma. Plus I didn't prove the statement If I don't prove that  $QM \cap N = Q(M\cap N) = QN$, so my idea has quite a lot of problems

Comment: Let $x\in M$, then $x= n + qy$ for some $n\in N, q\in Q, y\in M$. So, mod $N$, $x=qy$.

Comment: @Max So, as we can say that $x$ mod $N$ can be seen as $qx$ mod $N$ for some $q\in Q$, we can conclude, of course without using any isomorphism theorem. Is  that correct?